# Moodle: Combining the Two SQL for custom user profile fields

Tags: mysql, sql, moodle

Please help me to combine this two SQL statement so that it will in the $sql and will be interconnected. The final output is in the $sql and I can use **member_status** as field. Thanks

```
SELECT UID.data FROM prefix_user_info_field UIF, 
prefix_user_info_data UID WHERE UID.fieldid = UIF.id AND 
UIF.shortname = 'member_status' AND UID.userid = U.id) as 'member_status'";



$sql = "SELECT ci.id, u.id as userid, $userfields, co.id as courseid,
                   co.fullname as coursefullname, c.id as certificateid,
                   c.name as certificatename, c.verifyany
              FROM {customcert} c
              JOIN {customcert_issues} ci
                ON c.id = ci.customcertid
              JOIN {course} co
                ON c.course = co.id
              JOIN {user} u
                ON ci.userid = u.id
             WHERE ci.code = :code";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "SELECT ci.id, u.id as userid, $userfields, co.id as courseid,
               co.fullname as coursefullname, c.id as certificateid,
               c.name as certificatename, c.verifyany,
               d.data AS memberstatus
        FROM {customcert} c
        JOIN {customcert_issues} ci ON c.id = ci.customcertid
        JOIN {course} co ON c.course = co.id
        JOIN {user} u ON ci.userid = u.id
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT d.userid, d.data
            FROM {user_info_data} d
            JOIN {user_info_field} f ON f.id = d.fieldid AND f.shortname = 'member_status'
        ) d ON d.userid = u.id
        WHERE ci.code = :code";
```